# weird behavior with an index

Tags: jquery

Ok, I have a set of 14 multiple choice questions that appear in a display window one after another.

I am seeing some weird behavior with the last question being displayed twice (once leaving question 13 and into 14, and once again after leaving 14)

Heres the relevant parts of my code.

This is my first time using the eq() function, is it something in my understanding of how eq works?

From what I understand eq() just creates an index for whatever your pointing it at, in this case a set of elements with class = " question"

```
$(window).load(function() { 

$(".intro").appendTo('#display_box');
var question = $(".question");
var questionPosition = -1;


//clears out display window
function clearBox(){
    $("#display_box").children().fadeOut(500).appendTo('#question_holding');
};


// cycles through question index
function cycle(){

    question.eq(questionPosition).fadeIn(500).appendTo("#display_box");
    $("#display_box").animate({scrollTop:0}, 500);


}

$('#leftarrow').on('click', function(){
    questionPosition--;
    if (questionPosition < -1) {questionPosition = 13};
    clearBox();
    cycle();





});





$('#rightarrow').on('click', function(){
    questionPosition++;
    if (questionPosition > 13) { questionPosition = -1};
    clearBox();
    cycle();

    // if all questions are checked, display submit button

    if($('input[name^="answer"]:checked').length > 13 ) {
        $("#submit").css('display', 'block');
    }




});
```

Comment: Looks like a off-by-one to me.  try "if (questionPosition <= -1)" ?

Comment: Strange, Im 99% sure that was the first thing I tried... I think my brain has melted away lol 

Thank you tho,I probably screwed something else up when I tried that the first time. 

In any case it seems to work perfectly now

Comment: You may have tried it before changing questionPosition  to "-1".  Kinda does the same thing.